# Help to understand a proof (about filters)

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, lattice-orders, filters

Niels Diepeveen [claims that he has proved the following theorem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/NMTPqI8h13I/PVOLvGzraBAJ):

**Theorem** Consider the cofinite filter $F$ on an infinite set. Let $K$ be a collection of ultrafilters such that $\bigcap K=F$. Then for every $G\in K$ we have $\bigcap (K\setminus\{G\})=F$.

The proof is in [this USENET post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/NMTPqI8h13I/PVOLvGzraBAJ).

I do not understand the proof, see [this my USENET message](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/NMTPqI8h13I/NsZxHU0GAfgJ).

I ask to provide me with full detailed proof based on the [Niels Diepeveen's proof](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/NMTPqI8h13I/PVOLvGzraBAJ) or any other alternative proof.

Answer (score 2):

The claim "$\bigcap K$ is cofinite if and only if for every infinite $A$ there exists $G\in K$ with $A\in G$" is false. More precisely, forward direction is true, but the backward direction is wrong.

For instance, let $K$ be the set of all principal ultrafilters on $\omega$. It satisfies a stronger version of the given condition: if $A\subset\omega$ is nonempty, then there is $G\in K$ such that $A\in G$. Yet, $\bigcap K$ is the trivial filter; for, if $X\subset \omega$ is proper, then let $y\in \omega\setminus X$ and note that $X$ is not a member of the principal ultrafilter generated by $y$.

**Edit** As Niels Diepeveen says in a comment to this answer, the following modified statement is valid and as a result the rest of the proof goes through.

*Let $K$ be a collection of free ultrafilters. The intersection $\bigcap K$ is cofinite if and only if for every infinite set $A$, there exists $G\in K$ such that $A\in G$.*
*Proof*. Suppose $\bigcap K$ is cofinite, and let $A$ be a set such that no $G$ in $K$ contains $A$. Then, every member of $K$ contains the complement of $A$. Thus, the complement of the complement of $A$--i.e. $A$--is finite.

For the other direction, suppose $A$ is an infinite set in $\bigcap K$. If $A'$ is the complement of $A$ and is infinite, then note that $A'\in G$ for some $G\in K$. But this means $A\not\in G\supset\bigcap K$, a contradiction. q.e.d.

Comment: But how to prove that $\bigcap K$ being cofinite implies for every infinite $A$ there exists $G\in K$ with $A\in G$? If the whole proof of Niels Diepeveen correct?

Comment: @porton I have edited with details. Sorry for going back and forth, if you have followed my comments. The proof is incorrect.

Comment: @porton However, it is certainly plausible that $\bigcap K\setminus\{G\}$ is cofinite if $\bigcap K$ is cofinite. I will see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: In the context $K$ can be assumed to be a collection of *free* ultrafilters, because their intersection is assumed to be a free filter. Clearly then every subset of $K$ only contains free ultrafilters. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen Ah, thanks. I will edit.

Comment: I have posted a more detailed explanation of this point on Usenet. (not that I think you need it)

Comment: @NielsDiepeveen: Why $A'\in G$ for some $G\in K$?

Comment: I also do not understand the overall proof: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/NMTPqI8h13I/2U-qetLK_MgJ - pleas help.

Comment: @porton You seem to be thrown off by the following step: suppose there exists $A$ where $A\in G$ for a unique $G\in K$. The idea is that since this turns out to be impossible, every set occurring in $\bigcap K$ occurs in multiple members of $K$, so removing just one ultrafilter from $K$ has no effect (formally you can do an easy proof by contradiction to establish this last point).

Comment: @porton Also that first comment should probably have been directed at me (I am the author of the proof in my answer--Neils Diepeveen actually gave a more concise argument in that discussion you linked). $A'\in G$ for some $G$ because in that paragraph we are proving "if every infinite set lies in some ultrafilter in $K$, then $\bigcap K$ is cofinite", so since $A'$ is assumed to be infinite, we can use that hypothesis. Finally, I left out the point $\bigcap K\supset F$ from my proof: it is simply something I forgot to write.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: I am lost. Don't we suppose that $\bigcap K$ is **not** the cofinite filter? But $A'\in G$ would follow from $\bigcap K$ being a cofinite filter.

Comment: Summarizing: So now there are two things I don't understand: 1. How $\bigcap K$ not being the cofinite filter implies $\nexists \mathcal{G} \in K : A \in \mathcal{G}$ for every infinite set $A$. 2. Why each infinite $A$ occurs in at least two elements of $K$?

Comment: @porton That second paragraph is overall actually a direct proof (there is a proof by contradiction within it).

Comment: @porton Point 2. is the meat of Niels Diepeveen's proof. I suggest you discuss your doubts with him where your discussion has been already.

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld: See also my "I am lost." comment. I don't understand something.

Comment: @porton That's what I was trying to address. We are not assuming that $\bigcap K$ is not the cofinite filter. The contradiction at the end simply shows that any $A$ in $\bigcap K$ is the complement of a finite set.

Comment: OK, now I've understood everything. The proof is now in the preprint of my book, with proper thanks to Niels Diepeveen and Karl Kronenfeld.